# How can I cross reference a column name in a table?

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I have quite a big table in my latex document and in the text accompaning the table, I would like to state something like:

> As presented in column A in Table III, it is ...

I know how to cross reference the table, but how can I cross reference the column name? The reason I want to do that is that the column name might change and I don't want to search my document for all instances were I used the column name.

A simplified version of my table looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{The caption}
\label{tbl:data}
\tiny
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{l X c c c c c}
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} & \# Changed &F\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{X} & X1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
& X2 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &\\
& X3 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14\\
& X4 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: A working document around this table would be nice ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a version which will work with 'any' column title, writing a fake label into `.aux` and referring to it with `\nameref*`.

If the column title is just pure `A`, etc. another, counter-based approach would be better!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\columnheaddisplaystyle}[1]{%
  \textbf{#1}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelthis}[2]{%
  \columnheaddisplaystyle{#2}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\newlabel{#1}{{}{}{#2}{}}
  }%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{The caption} 
\label{tbl:data}
\tiny
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{l X c c c c c}
\labelthis{mycolumn}{A}  & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} & \# Changed &F\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{X} & X1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
& X2 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &\\
& X3 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14\\
& X4 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

As presented in column \nameref*{mycolumn} in Table \ref{tbl:data}, it is ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: @RoflcoptrException: Ok, I'll think about another approach nevertheless. Perhaps there's a package already for this